# Manacher's algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, palindrome

Is it necessary to use marker symbols(symbols in between characters in given string) while implementing Manacher's algorithm for Longest Palindromic Substring?

If yes, what happens if all the 256 symbols are used up?

Comment: Why would there be only 256 distinct symbols? Are you thinking about ASCII? If so, why not UTF-8, UTF-32, or even why restrict yourself to a character set rather than using arbitrary-length numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the algorithm on itself is already hard enough. If you would manage to do it without the markers, your code won't look very understandable.

Luckily there is no point to. The algorithm can work for arrays of any type. Like a string is just an array of characters. Just start with parsing your string into an array of the type that would be a fit for your encoding of choice and you're good. There is no complexity bound to the size of your data type.

Answer (score 0):

Manacher algorithm uses palindrom's property that it is symmetric around center. Finding center is relatively straight forward for odd length strings. Adding characters to even length string ensures string becomes of odd length. So, if your string is even length then it is necessary to add characters

Answer (score 0):

This question had already been answer and it is very old but I found my answer will be useful as most of the explanations of the Manacher’s Algorithm on the internet were written in hard to understand terms. So I implemented my own version of the algorithm. Of which is easier to understand. Besides that, opposite to what describe by the original algorithm, you do not need to use any marker. I just figured this out after looking at the algorithm and I think it will be useful as I think this is more efficient than the original algorithm.

The algorithm is very simple if you break it into routines.

Basically in my explanation, you move from left to right of the string.
You skip the first and the last character.

For the first character, although you skip that in your loop you compare it to the character that on its right. If it match, you have a palindrome of a length of 2 at that position.

Now for every character, you do 2 things.

1. Assume that character is not the center of a palindrome and start an outward match. For keeping track of the palindrome length, you need a variable with a value that start at 0. Now for the outward match loop, let consider 'i' is the character position then x is i and y is i + 1. After each loop, x is subtract to 1 and y is added to 1. You will try to match the character at x position to y position. If it match, increase the value of the length variable by 2. If not, just break out from this loop. If the length of this palindrome is longer than the longest palindrome you founded, replace the longest length with the length from this loop.
2. Assume that the character at the 'i' position is the center of a palindrome. For this, the loop is almost the same as the loop of 2, except the length of the palindrome variable is now start at 1. x will now start at 'i' - 1. However, y still start the same, and that is 'i' + 1. Everything else is the same.

Demonstration of how the algorithm work, I skip some position, because otherwise it would be too long. Also, below the demonstration is the programming code.

This algorithm is tested and passed submission on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/). However, I am trying to make it more efficient.

```
POS:  01234567
CHAR: abacabba
  (1) - Match next right (Only to position 0)
  (2) - Assume not center, outward match.
  (3) - Assume center, outward match.
  (PL) - Palindrome Length

  Position 0: (1) a != b (PL = 1(a))

  Position 1: (2) b != a (PL = 1(b))

              (3) center(b)
                  a(0) == a(2) (PL = 3(aba))

              Longest palindrome at this position is 3.

  Position 2: (2) a != c (PL = 1(a))

              (3) center(a)
                  b(1) != c(3) (PL = 1(a))

              Longest palindrome at this position is 1.

  .....
  Position 5: (2) b(5) == b(6)
                  a(4) == a(7) (PL = 4(abba);

              (3) center(b)
                  a(4) != b(6) (PL = 1(b);

              Longest palindrome at this position is 4.
```

This below is the code in C. I wrote it in a way that is very simple, it can be translated into almost any language with just some knowledge of C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x, y, len, lenM1, lPali, paliL, paliStart;
    // <- The demonstrate print code need word to be an array
    char word[] = "abcbcabbacba\0";  
    len = 12;        // < word len
    lenM1 = len - 1; // <- Len - 1;

    /* Manacher’s Algorithm Modified */
    // Word must be at least a length of 2.
    if ( word[0] == word[1] ) {
        lPali = 2;
        paliStart = 0;   
    } else {
        lPali = 1;
        paliStart = 0;
    }

    /* The loop */
    for ( int i = 1; i < lenM1; i++ ){
        int iP1 = i+1;

        /* Assume Not Center - if palindrome length is 0 
           it is a one. But 0 is unneccessary as any single 
           character can be a palindrome.
         */
        x = i;
        y = iP1;
        paliL = 0;
        while(1){
            if ( word[x] != word[y] ) {
                /*
                 * reverse so x = start;
                 * 
                 * Take note that if paliL is 0,
                 * x will not be correct. If there isn't a need to evaluate
                 * the correct x. That is fine. As paliL with length 0 will never
                 * be assigned. That is because all strings, whether contained 
                 * a palindrome or not, will start with a value of at least 1 for lPali.
                 * Any 1 character, in a string, by itself, is a palindrome of length 1.
                 * 
                 **/

                x++;
                break;
            }
            paliL += 2;
            if ( x == 0 || y == lenM1 ) break;
            x--;
            y++;
        }

        if ( paliL > lPali ){
            lPali = paliL;
            paliStart = x;
        }

        /* Assume Center */
        x = i - 1;
        y = iP1;
        paliL = 1;
        while(1){
            if ( word[x] != word[y] ) {
                // reverse so x = start;
                x++;
                break;
            }
            paliL += 2;
            if ( x == 0 || y == lenM1 ) break;
            x--;
            y++;
        }

        if ( paliL > lPali ){
            lPali = paliL;
            paliStart = x;
        }

        if ( lPali == len ) break;
    }

    word[paliStart + lPali] = 0;
    printf("%d\n", lPali);
    printf("%s", &word[paliStart]);
    return 0;
}
```